# Range support over time bucketed analytics

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, analytics

Read [this](https://www.compose.com/articles/first-steps-of-an-analytics-platform-with-mongodb/), and tried experimenting it.

Below is my schema.

**SCHEMA:**

```
{
    "s"  : "CB",
    "c"  : "REQ_RCV",
    "e"  : "sms_click",
    "st" : "i",
    "b"  : "2",
    "a"  : "1",
    "u"  : "b1_h1_d1_m1_user_2",
    "c#" : "b1_h1_d1_m1_cr-2",
    "@"  : ISODate("2016-10-01T06:03:00.000Z"), //Indexed
    "@h" : "16100106", //hourly bucket
    "@d" : "161001",                            //Indexed
    "@m" : "1610"
}
```

And below is the explain plan:

```
> 2017-01-22T13:43:47.764+0530 I COMMAND  [conn34] command test-analytics.template3 appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: aggregate {
> aggregate: "template3", pipeline: [ { $match: { @: { $gte: new
> Date(1483228800000), $lte: new Date(1483315199000) } } }, { $group: {
> _id: { b: "$b", HOURLY: "$@h", s: "$s" }, count: { $sum: 1.0 } } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, BUCKET: "$_id.b", SERVICE: "$_id.s", TIME:
> "$_id.HOURLY", count: 1.0 } }, { $sort: { SERVICE: 1.0, BUCKET: 1.0,
> TIME: 1.0 } } ], cursor: {} } planSummary: IXSCAN { @: 1.0 }
> keysExamined:106888 docsExamined:106888 hasSortStage:1
> cursorExhausted:1 numYields:925 nreturned:96 reslen:7095 locks:{
> Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1860 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r:
> 930 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 929 } } }
> protocol:op_command **3499ms**


> 2017-01-22T13:44:24.825+0530 I COMMAND  [conn34] command test-analytics.template3 appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: aggregate {
> aggregate: "template3", pipeline: [ { $match: { @d: "170101" } }, {
> $group: { _id: { b: "$b", HOURLY: "$@h", s: "$s" }, count: { $sum: 1.0
> } } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, BUCKET: "$_id.b", SERVICE: "$_id.s",
> TIME: "$_id.HOURLY", count: 1.0 } }, { $sort: { SERVICE: 1.0, BUCKET:
> 1.0, TIME: 1.0 } } ], cursor: {} } planSummary: IXSCAN { @d: 1.0 } keysExamined:106888 docsExamined:106888 hasSortStage:1
> cursorExhausted:1 numYields:865 nreturned:96 reslen:7095 locks:{
> Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1740 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r:
> 870 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 869 } } }
> protocol:op_command **1294ms**
```

**Questions**:

1. Though both the queries are examined same number of documents
   Why there is time difference in the output?
2. Are `$lte`, `$gte` operators slow only on date ranges or even slow on numeric comparison as well?
3. Since bucketing gives faster response, how do I use bucketing for range queries? I can make multiple aggregate time bucket calls to support range queries, but that will make more round trip time, any suggestions?
4. Is it possible to use `$and` for two `$match` in a aggregate query to support range bucketing? Currently aggregate accepts multiple `$match` but first output of `$match` is given to second `$match`, but what I want is adding/grouping of individual `$match` results to the next pipeline.

**Possible answer for Q4:**

```
db.template3.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"@d":"170301"},
                {"@d":"170306"}, 
                {"@d":"170202"}, 
                {"@d":"170303"},
                {"@d":"170304"}, 
                {"@d":"170305"}
            ]
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0, "b": 1, "s": 1, "@h": 1 } }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"b": "$b", "HOURLY": "$@h", "s": "$s" }, 
            count: { $sum: 1 } 
        }
    },  
    { 
        $project: {
            _id: 0, 
            "BUCKET": "$_id.b",
            "SERVICE": "$_id.s",
            "TIME": "$_id.HOURLY", 
            count: 1
        }
    },         
    { $sort: { "SERVICE": 1, "BUCKET": 1, "TIME": 1 } } 
]);
```

In this answer we can use mixes (daily and monthly) of buckets and still this will use its own index. Read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes.

**Sample query:**

```
db.template3.aggregate([ 

    {$match:{"@h":{$gte : 17020511, $lte : 17030511}, "st":"i"}}, 

    {$project : {"_id":0,  "@h":1,"c":1, "@m":1}}, 

    {$group:{_id:{ "HOURLY":"$@h", "c":"$c"}, count:{$sum:1}}},

    {$project : {_id:0, "COUNTER":"$_id.c","TIME":"$_id.HOURLY", count:1}}, 

    {$sort:{"COUNTER":1,"TIME":1}}
]);
```

**Output**:

```
{ "count" : 2255, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020511 }
{ "count" : 28888, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020600 }
{ "count" : 37613, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020601 }
{ "count" : 6723, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020602 }
{ "count" : 14057, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020603 }
{ "count" : 12405, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020604 }
{ "count" : 2392, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020611 }
{ "count" : 28784, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020700 }
{ "count" : 37494, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020701 }
{ "count" : 6697, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020702 }
{ "count" : 13930, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020703 }
{ "count" : 12493, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020704 }
{ "count" : 2225, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020711 }
{ "count" : 28821, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020800 }
{ "count" : 37949, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020801 }
{ "count" : 6676, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020802 }
{ "count" : 14039, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020803 }
{ "count" : 12349, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020804 }
{ "count" : 2332, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020811 }
{ "count" : 28379, "COUNTER" : "REQ_RCVD", "TIME" : 17020900 }
```

**OPTIMIZATION**

1. I felt more time is taken because of reading of non indexed fields.
   hence `docsExamined: 106888`
2. There is somehow an improvement when I use `$project` before `$group`
3. I have changed `"@h"` data type from `String` to `Integer` (`NumberInt`), I think it will improve some more.

Comment: Which version of Mongodb are you using? And can you add the expected output for range queries?

Comment: I am using the latest version of mongo, and i will update the output now.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I think you want to narrow down the range for each query by using the buckets so the index is better utilized. For example, if you store `hour` and `month` part like below, the range query `$gte : 17020111, $lte : 17033111` can be changed to `{"@m": {$in:{1702, 1703}}, "@h":11}` This may yield faster results. So you can use combination of non range operators to convert all your range queries to the granularity you need. Any api should be able to breakdown the input date to the buckets for you to query. Is that what you are after ?

Comment: Please consider to properly format the "explain" output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get to your question one by one:

> Though both the queries examined the same number of documents Why there is time difference in the output?

Looking at performance metrics from just a single execution is really not how it works. You should take the average over several executions before concluding because there are several factors at play. 
That being said, MongoDB caches most frequently used documents in memory and keeps it there unless it has to yield memory for some other document. So if a query access documents already cached from a previous query, it should be faster.

Also in MongoDB aggregation uses indexes only at the beginning if any. For example `$match` and `$sort`phases can use indexes. In your case `$match` is the first pipeline stage so that's a win.

> Is $lte, $gte is slow only on date range or it is even slow on numeric comparison as well ..?

In MongoDB data is stored in [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), so [dates are basically numbers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) when they are compared. So there is no difference.

> Since bucketing gives faster response, how to use bucketing for range queries? I can make multiple aggregate time bucket calls to support range queries, but that will make more round trip time, any suggestions?

Although I've not tested it I really doubt that the time_bucket approach will give faster response. Since `created_at` will always increase, the index, in this case, will also be appended to the end without the time_bucket. Furthermore, the index size will be comparatively huge when created on an array than on a simple date field. Will that not cause the issue of fitting the index in RAM.

Using a time_bucket makes sense when you are using some function on the date field before matching. If you extract only year from date field before matching, it will make the existing index on the date useless.

It's always better to cast your parameters to match the datatype in database instead of the other way around.

> Is that possible `$and` of two `$match` in an aggregate query to support range bucketing. Currently Aggregate accepts multiple `$match` but first output of $match is given to second $match, but what I want is adding/grouping of individual `$match` results to the next pipeline.

Yes, it's possible. If it's `$and`, you just specify all your filters separated by commas in the `$match` phase. If it's `$or` use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

If you have [two `$macth` phases one by one MongoDB combines it to one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#match-match-coalescence). So you don't need to worry about adding results of multiple match phases.

Now your **Optimization** Points

> I felt more time is taken because of reading of non-indexed fields. hence docsExamined:106888

Yes, [covered queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) are much faster.

> There is some betterment when I use $project before $group

If the size of documents is reduced in the `$group` stage by use of `$project`, then yes it's true.

> I have changed `@h` dataType from string to int (NumberInt), I think it will improve some more.

It's not necessarily true but it's generally the case. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16504625/2965883).

Comment: Thanks! for the answer, However i don't agree on lte, gte on date and numeric will be equal timedelay. since this item i have tested with 20 million records and found the time difference. also there are queries related to this StackOverflow.

Comment: That maybe because when you fetch a large number of records, those milliseconds needs to be converted to Date representation. Could you link other posts where date comparison turned out to be slower than number comparison?