# How to aggregate this data efficiently

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am looking to **aggregate** this data:

Full JSON: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24147839/

Sample:

```
{
"_id": "58c1b957f6d187a57dd4a458",
"stats": {
  "2017": {
    "3": {
      "9": {
        "6": {
          "49": {
            "sum": {
              "clicks": 1,
              "cost": 0.01
            }
          },
          "sum": {
            "clicks": 1,
            "cost": 0.01
          }
        },
        "sum": {
          "clicks": 1,
          "cost": 0.01
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I want to get is this : (this is just a sample, it will be one for each hour)

```
 "6": { clicks: 686 , cost: 3.05399999999995 }"
```

i took the *6* from `$stats.2017.3.9.6` and clicks is the `$stats.2017.3.9.6.sum.clicks` and `cost` is the sum of `$stats.2017.3.9.6.sum.cost`

What aggregation query should use to get this result ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Aggregation on dynamic fields is not possible. You may need to update your document structure to key value pair. Something like `{"date":"2016-05-18T16:00:00Z" , "sum": {
              "clicks": 1,
              "cost": 0.01
            }}`

Comment: Maybe using a map reduce function ?

Comment: The video you linked is from 2012 before aggregation was added to mongo db. If you are open to schema changes you can look at this use case. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/. This will get you started and you can use aggregate efficiently.

Comment: It's unclear whats to sum `6.sum` or `6.XX.sum` or both ? Please give expected output for the given input example you have supplied

Comment: Its right there, you can see the full JSON on the link , and then an example output is on the question (  "6": { clicks: 686 , cost: 3.05399999999995 }"  )

Comment: @Veeram , i just moved to that schema design , the speed of insertion has improved 300% , thanks , but now when im trying to query by hours, im facing the same issue. this is the data format: 

 {
    "_id": "58c5fe3884f55f55669ec53b",
    "hourly": {
      "6": 2,
      "8": 1,
      "9": 2,
      "15": 1,
      "17": 2,
      "19": 2,
      "21": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "58c5fe3884f55f55669ec6bb",
    "hourly": {
      "5": 1,
      "7": 1,
      "10": 1,
      "13": 1,
      "15": 1,
      "17": 2,
      "22": 1
    }
  } 
I need to know how to aggregate those

Comment: For querying/aggregation on specific fields, you will need to update your schema to include the data as array of key value pair document instead of one single document with variable keys. Something like `{ "_id": "58c5fe3884f55f55669ec53b", "hourly": [{hour: 6: count:2},{hour: 8: count:3} ... ]}`.  This is as such is very easy to aggregate `db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$hourly"},
{$group:{_id:"$id", sum:{$sum:"$hourly.count"}}})` but may not be efficient if you huge date range to aggregate over.

Comment: Its still little broad as I'm not entirely sure of all the requirements you have. So I can only recommend looking into more posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788874/range-support-over-time-bucketed-analytics. This will help you model your data better for high volumes and may be you can refine your post and ask something more specific.

Comment: do you want to aggregate by hour across all dates?  do you want to aggregate by hour for a specific date?  Your sample data is all for a single date so it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want to do this hourly aggregation for a particular day (your sample data is all for 2017-03-09 but let's assume that you do want to aggregate by hour for that particular date out of larger collection representing many days.   Here's the aggregation pipeline that would do it with any recent version:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$match:{"stats.2017.3.9":{$exists:true}}},
  {$project:{hours:[
      {hour:"00", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.0.sum"}, 
      {hour:"01", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.1.sum"},
      {hour:"02", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.2.sum"}, 
      {hour:"03", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.3.sum"}, 
      {hour:"04", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.4.sum"}, 
      {hour:"05", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.5.sum"}, 
      {hour:"06", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.6.sum"}, 
      {hour:"07", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.7.sum"}, 
      {hour:"08", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.8.sum"}, 
      {hour:"09", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.9.sum"}, 
      {hour:"10", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.10.sum"}, 
      {hour:"11", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.11.sum"}, 
      {hour:"12", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.12.sum"},   
      {hour:"13", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.13.sum"},   
      {hour:"14", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.14.sum"},   
      {hour:"15", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.15.sum"},   
      {hour:"16", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.16.sum"},   
      {hour:"17", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.17.sum"},   
      {hour:"18", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.18.sum"},   
      {hour:"19", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.19.sum"},   
      {hour:"20", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.20.sum"},   
      {hour:"21", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.21.sum"},   
      {hour:"22", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.22.sum"},   
      {hour:"23", sum:"$stats.2017.3.9.23.sum"}
  ]}}, 
  {$unwind:"$hours"},
  {$group: {
      _id    : "$hours.hour", 
      clicks : {$sum:"$hours.sum.clicks"},  
      cost   : {$sum:"$hours.sum.cost"}
  }}, 
  {$sort:{_id:1}}
])
```

This is first filtering to records that have data in "stats.2017.3.9", then it creates a new document with an hours array where for each hour it projects the metrics collected for that hour.  If such hour is not in the document, it will be null and ignored during grouping.  After unwinding the hours array we group by hour summing clicks and costs.

With your sample data the result is:

```
{ "_id" : "00", "clicks" : 93, "cost" : 0.419 }
{ "_id" : "01", "clicks" : 95, "cost" : 0.43 }
{ "_id" : "02", "clicks" : 86, "cost" : 0.427 }
{ "_id" : "03", "clicks" : 81, "cost" : 0.301 }
{ "_id" : "04", "clicks" : 92, "cost" : 0.423 }
{ "_id" : "05", "clicks" : 76, "cost" : 0.352 }
{ "_id" : "06", "clicks" : 91, "cost" : 0.397 }
{ "_id" : "07", "clicks" : 84, "cost" : 0.396 }
{ "_id" : "08", "clicks" : 95, "cost" : 0.353 }
{ "_id" : "09", "clicks" : 78, "cost" : 0.325 }
{ "_id" : "10", "clicks" : 100, "cost" : 0.40900000000000003 }
{ "_id" : "11", "clicks" : 96, "cost" : 0.405 }
{ "_id" : "12", "clicks" : 65, "cost" : 0.319 }
{ "_id" : "13", "clicks" : 90, "cost" : 0.395 }
{ "_id" : "14", "clicks" : 82, "cost" : 0.331 }
{ "_id" : "15", "clicks" : 85, "cost" : 0.38 }
{ "_id" : "16", "clicks" : 97, "cost" : 0.424 }
{ "_id" : "17", "clicks" : 27, "cost" : 0.125 }
{ "_id" : "18", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "19", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "20", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "21", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "22", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "23", "clicks" : 0, "cost" : 0 }
```